# How to convert any date to YYYYMMDDHHMMSS using unix shell script?

Tags: unix-timestamp

How to convert any date to `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` using unix shell script?
It is not specific date it may any date. how to convert it?
example date format is: `20110101050603`

Thanks
Puspa

Answer (score 3):

```
DATE = "15 Jun 2015 10:10:10"; date -d"$DATE" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
```

Output :-

```
20150615101010
```

[More on Dates](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats)
Note this only works on GNU date.
I have read that:

> Solaris version of date, which is unable to support -d can be resolve with replacing sunfreeware.com version of date.

**Update:-**
Use `ls` command to find all files and use `grep` command for all files.

```
ls | grep "[0-9]{14}"
```

`grep` command also accepts regular expression.
But it won't validate your file accurate. For example, if a file name is `20151835101010`, then it will validate this file. But actually month and date both are wrong.
So my suggestion is to write a shell script to identify valid file name and find oldest of them by processing one by one.

Comment: Ok thanks.I am having lot of files with YYYYMMDDHHMMSS timestamp format which is the valid format.And some of files having invalid date format.I would like to get all the file which is having valid timestamp(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)  and find the oldest file from the file which all having valid timestamp.example of valid files:xyz_abc.20150304043354.txt

Comment: No it is not working...it is taking the date like 1460eyewrtrerr also

Comment: You should explore `grep` command and regular expression as well. Use `man grep` command.